# How can i escape a string before sending in the body of a Rest request?

Tags: c#, json

I have a rest request. The body is like the following:

```
 RestClient client = new RestClient(uri);
 RestRequest request = new RestRequest("", Method.POST);
 request.AddHeader("Authorization", $"Bearer {myToken}");
 request.AddHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
 string json = "{'body': {'contentType': 'html','content': '" + message + "'}}";                    
 request.AddJsonBody(json);
 IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

The message contains apostrophes, like  John's so the json will be

```
       string json = "{'body': {'contentType': 'html','content': 'John's'}}";
```

This gives an error, Bad Request.
How can i accommodate for this and any other special characters in the message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to replace ' with \ "

```
string json= "{\"body\": {\"contentType\": \"html\",\"content\": \""+message+"\"}}";
```